# How to programmatically insert Text into DevExpress Rich Text Editor control?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I've a DevExpress Rich Text Editor control (ASPxRichEdit) into my asp.net webform page.

I would like to know how I can add text into it via C# server side code.

Doesn't exists corrisponding "MyTextBox.Text" method ?

Thanks

Comment: `richServer.Document.InsertText??` https://docs.devexpress.com/OfficeFileAPI/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditDocumentServer

Comment: I don't have .Document object when refering to my RichTextEdit instance...

Comment: And you've instantiated the new RichEditDocumentServer class and you still don't have the .Document property?